# On TFS Preview, Is there a way to tell which TFS servers I'm part of?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

My friend added me to a project under his TFS Preview account. I was sent the invitation email, but my friend didn't give me the Team foundation server URL!

Is there a way to tell which TFS servers i'm part of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to John Qiao [MSFT] on MSDN [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/32222244-65d1-47f7-bc24-4eaab96a4d4d/help-been-invited-to-a-project-but-dont-know-the-account-url): 
You cannot know that.

I sure hope Microsoft is going to add this feature soon.

Answer (score 1):

1. Browse to the Team Foundation Service home page (https://tfs.visualstudio.com/)
2. Click "Sign in"
3. Sign in using the Microsoft account you're interested in

You'll be directed to a page which will show you which accounts you own, or are a member of.

Comment: 4. Click on Account. And, no it doesn't show the projects I'm a member of, it only shows my account.